# Canvg error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'documentElement')

Tags: javascript, canvg

For my application I am using Canvg (also jsPDF, but that's not relevant) and when I invoke the canvg() method it gives me this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'documentElement')

Here is my code:

```
        svgToPng(svg, callback){
            let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            let data = svg.outerHtml;
            canvg(canvas,data);
            callback(canvas)
        },

        download(){
            let el = d3.select('svg');
            this.svgToPng(el, function(canvas) {
                let img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [50, 120]);
                doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 0, 0, 120, 50);
                doc.save('wordcloud.pdf')
            })
        }
```

Some extra info:

- I am loading Canvg in with a CDN

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvg/1.5/canvg.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have tried to do this with installing via NPM, but I got the same error.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: There is no reference to `documentElement` in the code posted. Does your error mention the file and which line the error is on?

Comment: @mykaf Ah I see. It points towards the canvg.min.js file. I find that quite odd though. You'd expect more questions on that issue if that happens with both the cdn and npm

Comment: for what it's worth. The error stays there even if you use a cdn of the normal package.

Comment: @mykaf Do you think this is an issue by the makers of the package? That would be problematic

Comment: Does your error have a stack trace? Sounds like the way you are calling canvg may be causing the error.

Comment: Perhaps try `let data = svg.outerHTML;` instead of `let data = svg.outerHtml;`.

Comment: @mykaf I just added the errors in a response below. Also. arent the 2 things you posted exactly the same?

Comment: No; javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: @mykaf , my bad. It didn't change anything though.

Comment: I think I have found something. Apparently the "data" is undefined. I'll do some testing and post when I have found something

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to the issue. Apparently I was following an outdated tutorial and "data" was undefined.

All I did was remove the .outerHtml, and it works.

Thanks for looking